# grey screen from strangers in Omegle

Tags: 18.04, flash, webcam

Since I've update to Ubuntu 18.04, I only have have grey screens from strangers in Omegle. I've tried Firefox and Chrome, same thing. My webcam works fine in Cheese and Skype, and Flash seems up to date... Not sure what is happening here, please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Someone say it is a NAT type problem.
Others a CORS cross origin request problem.

My view: something in the javascript engine of Omegle that windows accept but debian (and omegle) not.

In my case 90% of stranger camera are greyed out with the rolling icon, but I can see some strangers.

Consider also that Omegle runs (and could call) on different servers.